# How can I map a Spring Boot @RepositoryRestResource to a specific url?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-data, spring-boot

I cannot seem to be able to map my Repository in any location other than the following:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "item", path = "item")
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, Long> {
```

I thought I can use:

```
 path = "/some/other/path/item"
```

but the mapping does not resolve. I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /some/other/path/item. Reason:

Not Found
```

In spring-data javadoc `path` is defined as: ["The path segment under which this resource is to be exported."](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html#path%28%29)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mind if I ask what you ended up doing? I find myself in the exact same position as you.

Answer (score 17):

To change the base URI, you can also just add this to application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/my/base/uri
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to extend the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and override the `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)` to set yours `baseUri`. e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class MyRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    private static final String MY_BASE_URI_URI = "/my/base/uri";

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.setBaseUri(URI.create(MY_BASE_URI_URI));
    }
}
```

Comment: Much as it's frowned upon, I couldn't resist to add my "Thank You!" here: this saved a lot of head-scratching and you'd think that the Spring guys would have added this nugget of information to the reference documentation (or the Javadoc, or even the source code...) :)

Answer (score 5):

Correct application property is the following:
`spring.data.rest.base-path=/my/base/path` *(`base-path` instead of `base-uri`)*

Answer (score 4):

In spring boot 2

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter
{

   @Override
   public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)
   {
      config.setBasePath("/my/base/uri");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the path attribute is used to specify a path *segment* (so no slashes). The "/some/other/path" would have to be the servlet path or the context path (i.e. nothing to do with Spring Data).

Comment: Yes, but still... How do I publish this resource in /some/other/path/item? I thought, that I could specify it with the ```path``` variable. It **is** Spring Data that publishes it, shouldn't it be configurable where?

Comment: You'd have to take that up with the Spring Data devs. It's published as a servlet resource, so you *can* do it as any path you want by changing the servlet mappings. But "/" is a special character in URIs, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was forbidden in the path attribute of the Spring Data annotation. Why does it matter?