# Spring data-rest incorrect resource href

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm having trouble getting the correct url to show up for a self href using spring-data rest with spring-data jpa.

So I have a Student class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student", schema="main")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private StudentInformation studentInformation;
}
```

with a corresponding repository file

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "students", path = "students")
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

There is also a StudentInformation class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="studentinformation", schema="main")
public class StudentInformation {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
    ...
}
```

(other properties / getters / setters omitted)

with a corresponding repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "studentinformation", path = "students/studentinformation")
public interface StudentInformationRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentInformation, Long> {
}
```

The student displays as I would expect when i search for one by its id,

```
{
  "id": 1,
  ...
  ...
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/1"
    },
    "student": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/1"
    },
    "studentinformation": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/1/studentinformation"
    }
  }
}
```

except when I follow the link from students to studentInformation, studentInformation has an incorrect self link.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  ...
  ...
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/studentinformation/1"
    },
    "studentinformation": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/studentinformation/1"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get that link to read 
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/1/studentinformation
instead of 
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/students/studentinformation/1"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, multi-segment path like `students/studentinformation` just may not work as it is not supported, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438503/1889928), so don't focus on designing your URL's. If you really need to have `http://localhost:8080/students/1/studentinformation` representation - you need to define a custom controller for that and don't rely on `Spring Data REST`.

Secondly, wouldn't it be better to use [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) to have different student data on `/students` endpoint? If that's just a different representation of `Student` resource, I would go with projections, e.g. `students/1?projection=minimal` and `students/1?projection=full`.

In case `studentinformation` contains totally different data than the `students` and it is not a representation of `Student` resource, just define an endpoint for `/studentinformation`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you're saying there's no way to stack resources in a self href URL? like,

`http://localhost:8080/RESOURCE/{id}/SUB_RESOURCE`

using @RepositoryRestResource? I would have to define my own custom REST controllers? That seems weird

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you can check that in the link I've provided, not in the repositories at least. If you would find any way to do that - would be nice to know. The way it can be done is by defining @RepositoryRestController with your custom implementation and associate it with your resource.

Comment: If you want to go with repositories implementation, you can do `SUB_RESOURCE/{ID}?RESOURCE_ID={RESOURCE_ID}`