# Change Resource Path in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

With Spring Data REST, I'd like to change the path of a specific resource to be under a prefix i.e `http://example.net/api/customprefix/myresource` vs. `http://example.net/api/myresource`

I'm aware of how to change the *base path* of my Spring Data REST project using the `spring.data.rest.base-path` directive in `application.properties`, and this is currently set to `/api`

I have tried the following but I'm getting a 404 at `http://example.net/api/customprefix/myresource`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "customprefix/myresource", collectionResourceRel = "myresources")
public interface MyResourceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyResource, UUID> { }
```

Is it possible to set a custom prefix for a resource or group of resources with Spring Data REST?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible by design: [you can read an extended version of why exactly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396953/how-to-customize-spring-data-rest-to-use-a-multi-segment-path-for-a-repository-r?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Basically there is no reason why you would want to do this as the server or client doesn't need to know or understand the meaning of your URI. The `customprefix` has no meaning to the server or client whatsoever. You could just work with camel case or something like that to make your URI more readable.

In your case i.e. `path = "customprefix-myresource"`.