# Spring Boot Projection with RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a Class with details I want to hide. But I need to get it too. So I wrote a `Projection`. But it doesn't work as it should.

I'm writing School <> Teacher *(and so on)* model.

```
public class School{//...
```

has a `Set<Teacher>`.

This set shouldn't be visible from the 'main' path (which is School of course).

So here is the `Projection`:

```
@Projection(name = "noTeacher", types = {School.class})
public interface SchoolNoTeacher extends ProjectionModel {
    String getName();
    String getSkz();
}
```

no `getTeachers()`!

This is default in my `Repository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "school", excerptProjection = SchoolNoTeacher.class)
public interface SchoolRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<School, Long> {//...
```

But I want to handle the rest path myself. So I've a controller too.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ScoolModel.api + "/school")
public class SchoolRestController {//...
```

And the Projection is not working. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `@RestController` and a `@RepositoryRestResource` together.  With Spring Data Rest, The RepositoryRestResource is essentially a Controller and a Repository combined together to produce a HATEOAS service endpoint.

If you need to customize your base URI, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30767002/1435451).

Comment: and what about `Projection`?

Comment: If you let the `@RepositoryRestResource` handle the end point as intended, the projections should work as expected.

Comment: I dropped the resources now

Comment: See also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186914/1474069