# How to customize Spring Data REST to use a custom path for a repository resource?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm developing a microservice using SPRING DATA REST where I need to sub-resources to be accessible only thru main resource like the following structure :

```js
http://localhost:8080/posts
http://localhost:8080/posts/1/comments
```

and block direct access to sub-resource directly like this `http://localhost:8080/comments/*`.

where comments must be accessible only thru related poste , I did the following in my repository :

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "posts", path = "posts")
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long> {
   ...
}
```

for comments :

```java
 @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "comments", path = "comments")
    public interface CommentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Comment, Long> {
       ...
    }
```

now by default SPRING DATA REST returns the following results when i goto to : `http://localhost:8080`

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "some post text .........................",
  "author":"abc",
  
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/posts/1"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/posts/1/comments"
    }
  }
}
```

now if i want to post a comment i need to do the following :

```js
 http://{server:port}/comment METHOD:POST
    
    {"author":"abc","content":"PQROHSFHFSHOFSHOSF", "post":"http://{server:port}/post/1"}
```

but what i need to achienve is to POST to an url like this `http://{server:port}/posts/1/comment` where the **POST** **is the root resource**  **NOT** like the previous path  `http://{server:port}/comment`

```js
 http://{server:port}/posts/1/comment METHOD:POST
    
{"author":"abc","content":"PQROHSFHFSHOFSHOSF", "post":"http://{server:port}/post/1"}
```

i now that this is possible if a create a custom **comment** `@controller` but i want to use the already building features of SPRING DATA REST and Hateoas support .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I map a Spring Boot @RepositoryRestResource to a specific url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577400/how-can-i-map-a-spring-boot-repositoryrestresource-to-a-specific-url)

Comment: No unfortunately this not solve my problem.